# How to put a timer to a TCP socket?

Tags: android, sockets, tcp

I need your help. I want to do this: I have a `socket TCP` and a `Timer` task in my `IntentService`. This is my code:

```
 protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent)
{
    String add = intent.getStringExtra("address");
    Log.d("add",add);
    int porta = Integer.parseInt(intent.getStringExtra("port"));
    InetAddress serverAddr = null;
    try
    {
        serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(add);
        socket = new Socket(serverAddr, porta);
        socketHandler.setSocket(socket);


        final PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())),true);
        out.print("go");
        out.flush();

        final byte[] bytes = new byte[1000];
        int counter;
        String reader;
        final InputStream data = socket.getInputStream();

        int numRead = 0;

        if ((numRead = data.read(bytes)) >= 0)
        {
            reader=new String(bytes, 0, numRead);
        }

        if (reader.equals("Let's go"))
        {
         //socket connected
        }

        pingTimer = new Timer();
        pingTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            String reader; int r;

            public void run()
            {


               out.write("ping");
               out.flush();

               if(out.checkError())
               {
                  onDestroy();
               }
            }

        }, 0, 20000);

        InputStream readeIn = socket.getInputStream();
        char [] buffer = new char[1024];

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(readeIn));

        while((counter = in.read(buffer)) != -1)
        {

         //read here
        }

    catch (UnknownHostException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        onDestroy();
    }
}

public void onDestroy()
{
 //destroy socket
}
```

and it works well. Now I want to do this: I want to put a timer to the socket. So, the socket is up for 3 minutes; if it receives something, re-put 3 minutes to listen, but if in these 3 minutes socket doesn't receive anything, I want to close the socket. How can I do it?
Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `Socket.setSoTimeout()` with an argument of `3*60*1000` which corresponds to three minutes (times 60 to give seconds, times 1000 to give milliseconds), and handle the resulting `SocketTimeoutException` accordingly.

Comment: Never tried that function but it looks as if you dont have to do anything else. The socket will be closed if there is nothing read in assigned interval. That interval will start again after every successfull read. Doesnt it work that way?